# hibernate second level ehcache miss

Tags: java, hibernate, ehcache

I'm trying to get a second-level hibernate cache working, using the ehcache implementation.

I'm sure it's some obvious noob mistake I'm making, but I can't see what it is!

To test out my cache, I'm doing the following:

Creating an object and saving it. I 'get' it once within the transaction, where I can see I get the object back without a db hit, which is just the hibernate first level cache doing its thing.

Then I commit the transaction and start a new session.

This time, when I 'get' the object, I can see a cache miss from ehcache in the debugs. I would have expected the object to be in the cache now since I saved it in the previous transaction?

Here's my code:

```
  Session session = getSession();   
  session.beginTransaction();

  Test1 test1a = new Test1();
  test1a.setId(5);
  test1a.setName("Test 1");
  test1a.setValue(10);
  // Touch it
  session.save(test1a);

  // Now get it
  Test1 test1b = (Test1)session.get(Test1.class, 5);

  // Within a transaction, the session caches it - no db hit
  System.out.println("GOT object with value "+test1b.getValue());

  session.getTransaction().commit();

  System.out.println("Between sessions");

  session = getSession();
  session.beginTransaction();

  test1b = (Test1)session.get(Test1.class, 5);

  System.out.println("GOT object with value "+test1b.getValue());

  session.getTransaction().commit();
```

And here's the relevant part of my hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<property name="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.EhCacheProvider</property>
```

And my ehcache.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <ehcache xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://ehcache.sf.net/ehcache.xsd"> 
    <cache name="com.play.hibernate1.Test1" maxElementsInMemory="1000" eternal="false"     timeToLiveSeconds="600" overflowToDisk="false"/>
    <defaultCache maxElementsInMemory="10000" eternal="false"
overflowToDisk="true" timeToIdleSeconds="10" timeToLiveSeconds="20" diskPersistent="true" />
    </ehcache>
```

And my annotations

```
@Entity
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
public class Test1 {
```

And the debug logs

```
11:21:03,474 DEBUG CacheManager:239 - Configuring ehcache from classpath.
11:21:03,479 DEBUG ConfigurationFactory:122 - Configuring ehcache from ehcache.xml found in the classpath: file:/Users/bw/Documents/workspace/hibernate1/target/classes/ehcache.xml
11:21:03,479 DEBUG ConfigurationFactory:87 - Configuring ehcache from URL: file:/Users/brucewood/Documents/workspace/hibernate1/target/classes/ehcache.xml
11:21:03,480 DEBUG ConfigurationFactory:139 - Configuring ehcache from InputStream
11:21:03,485 DEBUG BeanHandler:213 - Ignoring ehcache attribute xmlns:xsi
11:21:03,485 DEBUG BeanHandler:213 - Ignoring ehcache attribute xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation
11:21:03,517 DEBUG ConfigurationHelper:208 - No CacheManagerEventListenerFactory class specified. Skipping...
11:21:03,518 DEBUG ConfigurationHelper:183 - No CachePeerListenerFactoryConfiguration specified. Not configuring a CacheManagerPeerListener.
11:21:03,518 DEBUG ConfigurationHelper:159 - No CachePeerProviderFactoryConfiguration specified. Not configuring a CacheManagerPeerProvider.
11:21:03,525 DEBUG ConfigurationHelper:135 - No BootstrapCacheLoaderFactory class specified. Skipping...
11:21:03,526 DEBUG ConfigurationHelper:135 - No BootstrapCacheLoaderFactory class specified. Skipping...
11:21:03,532 DEBUG MemoryStore:73 - Initialized net.sf.ehcache.store.LruMemoryStore for com.play.hibernate1.Test1
11:21:03,533 DEBUG LruMemoryStore:71 - com.play.hibernate1.Test1 Cache: Using SpoolingLinkedHashMap implementation
11:21:03,533 DEBUG Cache:429 - Initialised cache: com.play.hibernate1.Test1
1528 [Finalizer] INFO org.hibernate.connection.DriverManagerConnectionProvider - cleaning up connection pool: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/play
1668 [main] INFO org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryObjectFactory - Not binding factory to JNDI, no JNDI name configured
GOT object with value 10
Hibernate: 
    /* insert com.play.hibernate1.Test1
        */ insert 
        into
            Test1
            (name, value, id) 
        values
            (?, ?, ?)
1274984463818|1|1|batch|/* insert com.play.hibernate1.Test1 */ insert into Test1 (name, value, id) values (?, ?, ?)|/* insert com.play.hibernate1.Test1 */ insert into Test1 (name, value, id) values ('Test 1', 10, 5)
1274984463820|1|1|statement|/* insert com.play.hibernate1.Test1 */ insert into Test1 (name, value, id) values (?, ?, ?)|/* insert com.play.hibernate1.Test1 */ insert into Test1 (name, value, id) values ('Test 1', 10, 5)
1274984463821|1|1|commit||
Between sessions
11:21:03,823 DEBUG EhCache:68 - key: com.play.hibernate1.Test1#5
11:21:03,823 DEBUG MemoryStore:138 - com.play.hibernate1.Test1Cache: com.play.hibernate1.Test1MemoryStore miss for com.play.hibernate1.Test1#5
11:21:03,823 DEBUG Cache:661 - com.play.hibernate1.Test1 cache - Miss
11:21:03,824 DEBUG EhCache:77 - Element for com.play.hibernate1.Test1#5 is null
Hibernate: 
    /* load com.play.hibernate1.Test1 */ select
        test1x0_.id as id0_0_,
        test1x0_.name as name0_0_,
        test1x0_.value as value0_0_ 
    from
        Test1 test1x0_ 
    where
        test1x0_.id=?
1274984463829|4|1|statement|/* load com.play.hibernate1.Test1 */ select test1x0_.id as id0_0_, test1x0_.name as name0_0_, test1x0_.value as value0_0_ from Test1 test1x0_ where test1x0_.id=?|/* load com.play.hibernate1.Test1 */ select test1x0_.id as id0_0_, test1x0_.name as name0_0_, test1x0_.value as value0_0_ from Test1 test1x0_ where test1x0_.id=5
1274984463831|-1||resultset|/* load com.play.hibernate1.Test1 */ select test1x0_.id as id0_0_, test1x0_.name as name0_0_, test1x0_.value as value0_0_ from Test1 test1x0_ where test1x0_.id=5|name0_0_ = Test 1, value0_0_ = 10
GOT object with value 10
1274984463834|0|1|commit||
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: So far I've traced it to initial save - I can see it's not in the cache after that. However, it IS in the cache after I retrieve it from the database, and then I can get it back from the cache. So it looks as if my save is not putting it into the cache.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem was that I was using NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE. It seemed to fit the bill from this explanation in the docs:

> If the application only occasionally
>   needs to update data (i.e. if it is
>   extremely unlikely that two
>   transactions would try to update the
>   same item simultaneously), and strict
>   transaction isolation is not required,
>   a nonstrict-read-write cache might be
>   appropriate. If the cache is used in a
>   JTA environment, you must specify
>   hibernate.transaction.manager_lookup_class.
>   In other environments, you should
>   ensure that the transaction is
>   completed when Session.close() or
>   Session.disconnect() is called.

but actually it looks like it doesn't add saved objects to the cache.. Docs are a little thin here, IMO. There is a better treatment of the caching options in Java Persistence with Hibernate, although still a little thin on concrete explanation of what actually happens to your data. Anyway..

I changed my caching option to READ_WRITE, and now it works as expected.

Note also that the first time an object gets added to the cache, you get a 'cache miss' in the ehcache debugs. Presumably it looks in its cache, finds the object is not there, records a miss, then adds the object. After that, you get 'hits'.

Comment: +2 for the question and the answer

Answer (score 0):

Also be wary of the bug in org.hibernate.action.internal.BulkOperationCleanupAction.#affectedEntity see discussion in both

https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=998970

and

https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-4035